# Yii2 - Merge two models and return as JSON

Tags: yii, yii2

In Yii2 Framework, is it possible to merge two models and return it as a one JSON object.
Below are the two object retrieved from database

```
public function actionJson()
{
   \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
   $result = Result::findOne(1);
   $user = User::findOne(1);
   // Merge two objects 
   // Something like this
   $model = $result + $user;
   return $model;
}
```

Comment: You could return an array with two elements: [0] => result and [1] => user

Answer (score 4):

You could assign the 2 to  an associative  array  with key based on the model name

```
  public function actionJson()
  {
     \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
     $result = Result::findOne(1);
     $user = User::findOne(1);

     //
     $myModels['result'] = $result;
     $myModels['user'] = $user;

      return $myModels;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. It's useful for someone

```
$myModels['result'] = $result->getModels();
$myModels['user'] = $user->getModels();
```